# d3-force-directed-graph with background image to entire diagram with zoom functionality

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am new to D3js chart I have developed the d3 force-directed graph and also I want to add a background image to the entire graph with zoom functionality.

Actually, the requirement is using d3 force-directed graph I want plot the nodes at specific locations with the reference of the background image like the below image

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3FW2.jpg)

**The expectation is when the user zoom on the diagram both the diagram and background image get zoom in simultaneously
**?
I don't know how to achieve this in d3 chart
Can you help me, please

**The expectation is when the user zooms on the diagram both the diagram and background image get zoomed in simultaneously
**?
I don't know how to achieve this in the d3 chart
Can you help me, please